# App crashes on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, crash, iphone-3gs

This code causes my app to crash on an iPhone 4 and on the simulator but works perfectly fine on a 3GS.  Any ideas why this might be?

```
-(IBAction)startButtonClicked{

 GameViewController *screen = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
 [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
 [screen release]; 
}
```

Comment: Check the console and see if anything useful is being printed there. My guess is something is amiss in your GameViewController.

Comment: I get this in the console: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: Are you using a file path that may not be present on the iPhone 4?  Use breakpoints on exceptions and a stack trace to determine what line of code is causing that exception.

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out what's happening in screen's viewWillAppear and viewWillLoad methods?  It looks like some issue in your init code there.  Where are you opening a URL?